# Rails javascript include only specific page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to include only javascript src I want to a specific page instead of the layout page (application.html.erb)

Comment: We have published a gem that resolves this issue, check the blog post http://eng.wolox.com.ar/blog/2013/04/19/introducing-loadjs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your rails project you have

```
app/assets/javascripts/application.js
```

which probably contains this line

```
//= require_tree .
```

The `require_tree` word means to include all your JavaScript files to project.
So just remove it and put files that you need:

```
//= require your_js_file
```

Comment: Would that mean that I could specify which file to be included in which page?

Comment: No by default, you can control that by <%= javascript_include_tag "application"%> in your layout. You can create several layouts and put specific set of files to every layout.